# How are score streaks meant to be obtained?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

So I was watching some video footage of good players and I'm totaly confused now.

For me score streaks seem to work completely differently. If I die, I need to regain all the score streaks again (even when I already have them), but on the footage it seemed that when the player kept the first two score streaks and died, he started gaining the third one.

Am I missing something completely obvious here? Is there some switch as to which score streak I want to gain points for?

Comment: Could you link the footage?  As far as I know, your points towards pointstreaks reset every time you die in BO2.  There was a MW3 strike package that didn't have this limitation, however.

Comment: It is highly likely that what you are seeing is the player starting to gain their first scorestreak again. But the UI still highlights the first two as they are still available for use once obtained (even after death)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike MW3, where you could use support killstreaks, in Black Ops 2 all the scorestreak has to be obtained in one life. If you get the scorestreak but are killed before you have time to use it then you will still have it when you spawn but will start your streak again at 0; this much is the same as with Assault killstreaks in MW3.

If you could link the footage, I'd be intrigued to see it.